# TypeError: DataFrame.assign() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So I'm trying to be a good person and re-write this:

```
df1["Cum Correct"] = df1.groupby(level=0)["Correct"].cumsum()
```

which triggers the over-zealous SettingWithCopyWarning with this:

```
tmp={'Cum Correct': df1.groupby(level=0)["Correct"].cumsum()}
df1= df1.assign(tmp)
```

as based on what I read using assign is the correct approach. However this gives me the error:

```
TypeError: assign() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try to unpack the `tmp` dict:

```
df1= df1.assign(**tmp)
```